# Charts.js: Load new data set to an existing chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I need to load a new group of data, replacing the existing one, to an existing chart when a button is clicked.

I'm trying using `myChart.data = data2;` and `myChart.update();`, but nothing happens.

Here is my complete code: http://codepen.io/marcelo2605/pen/zogjvj?editors=0010

Comment: If you change `myChart.data = data2;` to `myChart.data.datasets[0].data = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80];` in your codepen example, it seems to work. The documentation for Charts.js indicates you should be able to change the entire data object though, so it doesn't really explain why your code isn't working as expected.

Comment: @JeremyE Fixed! Thanks for the tip. I will post the solution.

Comment: I'm glad that helped. I'm still a little curious why what you had didn't work as expected, but at least you have a good work around.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:

```
$('#btn-load').on('click', function(){
    myChart.data.datasets[0] = data2['datasets'][0];
    myChart.data.labels = data2['labels'];
    myChart.update();
});
```

http://codepen.io/marcelo2605/pen/zogjvj?editors=0010